# Very interesting Bonus 1.5 GB "space" from .... space?

Tags: partitioning, usb, filesystem

[image]

I use a 4 GB stick with Ubuntu, which has unknown 1.5 GB space. Can some one explain from where this 1.5 GB comes from ?

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting. I just learned what this is myself. You can see the actual information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device), but will still summarize it for you.

As you can see from the far left side of that "drive", is that it's a different mount point. /dev/loop0, to be specific. You can also see that your USB device is being recognized as a cdrom.

The 1.5GB of space is known as a **loop device**. To my understanding, it is used for holding installation files and programs while they are running so in the event your "CD" is removed, the program won't crash and potentially corrupt your system. It is also much faster to run a program locally, rather than through your USB port.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This 1.5 GB is a squashfs from /dev/loop0 device - filesystem in a file which is on your pendrive.